# How can I completely remove Serviio DLNA Server from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, streaming, dlna

I uninstalled Serviio DLNA Server from Windows 7, because I prefer the DLNA server built into my router. But now any DLNA clients I use still recognize this as an available server in the list of choices, and this is confusing to family members. I don't believe this information is cached, because of the amount of time it takes to discover or refresh DLNA servers. It seems that a configuration or setting still remains on my system, and is broadcasting itself as a DLNA server.

What is the best way to completely remove this from my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Type “Manage advanced sharing settings” in the Start Menu
2. Go to “Home and Work”
3. Under “Media Streaming” you click the “Choose media streaming options” link
4. Click the “Block all” button followed by the “OK” button

http://pario.no/2012/01/26/disable-dlna-in-windows-7/